# Why can't I move my pirates?

Tags: psp, sid-meiers-pirates

I am playing Sid Meier's Pirates on the PSP again, since playing it for 20 years on the PC was not enough. But when I try to move my Pirates! in strategic mode when attacking a Town, X does only select, but not move them.

As I said, I played the original on the C64 and I played the remake on the PC, which is identical to the PSP Version. But this really puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X doesn't control the movements of the Pirates. You need to move around with your left stick to move. If for some reason It isn't working you need to reconfigure the settings so your movements line up with game controls.

Comment: Thanks now I feel stupid. I was only looking at the buttons on the controls screen. Using the analog stick for direction and X to confirm works. I was using the dpad to move the selection cursor and expected my Pirates! to go there when I press X :D.

Comment: @leetfan Ya no problem when you first start off it's a little confusing